# How to update a record from client to server without displaying unique_Id to user

Tags: javascript, database

How does one update a record from the client to the database without displaying `Unique_id` of that record to the client.

My problem is that if I display it to the user with `display:none` property, the user can inspect and change that particular unique_id to some random number, which in case might match with other record's unique_id and end up with updating other record (wrong record).

Comment: what want you to do exactly , do the connected person have the ability to edit other info or just his info only

Comment: just to edit his info only

Comment: please see my answer , if you have any question just comment it :) , also can you mention wich backend langage you're using

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question and the approach to prevent the tampering of Id from the client side could be like:

Basically, the idea is to create a token that is simply the hash of a salt/key + record ID.

Algorithmic Steps:

> Record the Id from the (SELECT) query.
>
> Create a token with salt + Id and save it for later use.
>
> Include this token in your form data as a hidden field when data is
>   sent for update at the client side.
>
> Now, when the user posts the data to the script that handles the form
>   submission, you can allow update if token that was sent equals the one
>   temporarily stored on the server.

```
if(tokenSavedOnServer != tokenCameFromClient)
{
  // Id has been tampered. Cancel update request.
}
```

This can also be made more robust by including timestamp in the token and check  if the timestamp is not older than 10 mins or whatever time.

So, any request coming in for ANOTHER ID will not lead to any UPDATE, because the records aimed at will not be having the same token strings.

Answer (score 0):

By Unique_id of that record, I assume you are talking about primary key of that table. You don't have to deal with database operations on the client side. All you have to do is just send the data from the client to the backend script (could be node.js, PHP, etc) and let your backend code handle all the database operations.

EDIT:

After understanding your problem clearly I can think of one possible solution. If there is a session you are maintaining (requires user to login) then when the user sends his id from the client side, you can verify it on the server side by storing a copy of his id on the server.

Comment: i think her problem is that users can change id and then on her backend she couldn't handle that case

Comment: exacty @MSekrst

Comment: well all one has to do is send data to the backend through a POST request via a form and let the backend script handle the rest. On the backend side, all you have to do is check a condition if the current user has permission to alter the values of that row.

Comment: Hi user3807678, still you couldn't get my problem, I'm Intermediate and not beginner.

Comment: Lets say I am a user with id = 1, so you are afraid that I might change my id = 2, and update the values for user with id = 2, right?

Comment: okay, I have all your info, lets say(email,phoneNo and so on), when you click on edit button of a page, I will display all your info in addition with unique_Id with (display:none) property by which I can know which record is to be updated when user(you) click save button, If you inspect the browser and change your unique id lets say(id=142) which might match with one of your friends record and you don't have permission to access.

Comment: Before executing the changes requested by the user on the backend, you have to check if the id you have received from the user is indeed his/hers and not of someone else. You can do this by storing a copy of his id on the backend as well, and check if the id submitted by the client and that on the server are one and the same. If yes, then save changes else do not.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide actual id from users on frontend you could encrypt it and then back on server you can decript it.

Comment: anyother possible way @MSekrst, or is this a way all do.?

Comment: you could change database design in matter that by knowing id you can't easly modify it and guess other id. That can be done by hashing ids, using random char sequences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the User has only to edit his Info :

You have tow possibilties :

1. **Use the id from the client side** :

   Whether  he change it or not , you can store the `id` at the backend , then before start edit check the sended id if it is the same as the id Session stored value , ( and this to prevent multiple query to database ) otherwise you'll make a query to get connected user info and check if Id is equals  , if yes perform edit else return permission error .
2. **Without using id** :

   so in this case , after sending the info , same thing as the first , if you already stored ID in session , just perform the edit , if not , you have to grab user info then make an update using the returned id from the first query .

both action are the same , but I recomand to store the ID in the session when the client is connected ,so you make the update query directly without make a search for this last ,

So , Sotre Id in session when client connected then perform update using id session var, and this  without setting id on the client side .